# NPM manual review not working after updating packages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, sass, node-sass

I downloaded node-sass and after doing so I received this message "found 9 vulnerabilities (4 moderate, 5 high) in 1869 scanned packages
9 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details." The thing is that I tried to install every new version manually with `npm install <packagename>@version --save-dev` as a lot of people have suggested but I still get the same warning message, with 4 moderate and 5 high vulnerabilities, so it's not working.

I have also tried `npm update`, `npm audit fix` and `npm audit fix --force` but no luck.

```
Moderate        Regular Expression Denial of Service                          

  Package         postcss                                                       

  Patched in      >=7.0.36 <8.0.0 || >=8.2.10                                   

  Dependency of   react-scripts                                                 

  Path            react-scripts > resolve-url-loader > postcss                  

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1693                             


  Moderate        Regular Expression Denial of Service                          

  Package         browserslist                                                  

  Patched in      >=4.16.5                                                      

  Dependency of   react-scripts                                                 

  Path            react-scripts > react-dev-utils > browserslist                

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1747                             


  Moderate        Regular expression denial of service                          

  Package         glob-parent                                                   

  Patched in      >=5.1.2                                                       

  Dependency of   react-scripts                                                 

  Path            react-scripts > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 >   
                  chokidar > glob-parent                                        

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1751                             


  Moderate        Regular expression denial of service                          

  Package         glob-parent                                                   

  Patched in      >=5.1.2                                                       

  Dependency of   react-scripts                                                 

  Path            react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > chokidar > glob-parent   

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1751                             


  High            Regular Expression Denial of Service                          

  Package         trim-newlines                                                 

  Patched in      >=3.0.1 <4.0.0 || >=4.0.1                                     

  Dependency of   node-sass                                                     

  Path            node-sass > meow > trim-newlines                              

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1753                             


  High            Denial of Service                                             

  Package         css-what                                                      

  Patched in      >=5.0.1                                                       

  Dependency of   react-scripts                                                 

  Path            react-scripts > @svgr/webpack > @svgr/plugin-svgo > svgo >    
                  css-select > css-what                                         

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1754                             


  High            Denial of Service                                             

  Package         css-what                                                      

  Patched in      >=5.0.1                                                       

  Dependency of   react-scripts                                                 

  Path            react-scripts > optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin > cssnano  
                  > cssnano-preset-default > postcss-svgo > svgo > css-select   
                  > css-what                                                    

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1754                             


  High            Regular Expression Denial of Service                          

  Package         normalize-url                                                 

  Patched in      >=4.5.1 <5.0.0 || >=5.3.1 <6.0.0 || >=6.0.1                   

  Dependency of   react-scripts                                                 

  Path            react-scripts > mini-css-extract-plugin > normalize-url       

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1755                             


  High            Regular Expression Denial of Service                          

  Package         normalize-url                                                 

  Patched in      >=4.5.1 <5.0.0 || >=5.3.1 <6.0.0 || >=6.0.1                   

  Dependency of   react-scripts                                                 

  Path            react-scripts > optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin > cssnano  
                  > cssnano-preset-default > postcss-normalize-url >            
                  normalize-url                                                 

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1755
```

**Package json**

```
{
  "name": "wineharvest",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "normalize-url": "^4.5.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "glob-parent": "^5.1.2",
    "postcss": "^7.0.36"
  }
}
```

Any idea of what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** After researching for a few hours, I've found a solution. If nothing works, install the package that gives you problems, for example, `npm install postcss --save-dev`.Then, add this to your `package.json` file:

```
{
  "resolutions": {
    "postcss": "^7.0.36"
  }
}
```

if you're using `npm`, then you should add this to your scripts too:

```
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
}
```

After you've installed the packages and added them to your `package.json`as previously mentioned, then you can run `npm install`. You should be able to see 0 vulnerabilities.

For more information, refer to the source where all of this is explained: [source for this issue](https://itnext.io/fixing-security-vulnerabilities-in-npm-dependencies-in-less-than-3-mins-a53af735261d)

Comment: Can you please explain why it make difference in package.json becuase of npm ?

Comment: @MukulSharma According to npm documentation, "This packages (npm-force-resolutions) modifies package-lock.json to force the installation of specific version of a transitive dependency (dependency of dependency), similar to yarn's selective dependency resolutions, but without having to migrate to yarn. (...) The use case for this is when there is a security vulnerability and you MUST update a nested dependency otherwise your project would be vulnerable." It should be used as a last resource. Check here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions